# Force Script to run in Python 3

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, kivy

I have a script that I wrote in Python 3, and while experimenting with GUIs, I found one I seemed to like called Kivy.  Everyone is saying it works with Python 3, but whenever I run it, it runs in Python 2.7.  How can I either

A: Get Kivy to run in Python 3 completely

or

B: Force the script that part of my Kivy app calls to run in Python 3.

I'm on OS X 10.10 with both python 3 and 2 installed.

I just tried

**myModule.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
def getVersion():
    return sys.version_info
```

Where I run `kivy myapp.py` that all it does it print a label with getVersion() as the content of that label.
But that still seems to show 2.7.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in the GUI?

Comment: Are you sure you have the python 3 version of Kivy installed?  If so, are there two kivy executables (like maybe "kivy" and "kivy3")?

Comment: There aren't 2 versions as far as I can tell.  It just says it supports python 3 but always runs in 2.7 mode.

Answer (score 7):

She-bang the Python version that you want your GUI to run, using something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

at the top of the `.py` file. 
Alternatively, you can set up your `virtualenv` to run Python 3 with the command-line argument:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when I do that. `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4

import sys
print(sys.version_info)
`

Answer (score 1):

The package for OSX is built for Python 2.7 - it will not run with Python 3.x. While the code is compatible with either Python version, the compiled parts must be compiled for one or the other and not both.

You *may* be able to use Python 3.3 by modifying the `kivy.sh` script and changing the command from `python2.7` to `python3.3`, then entering the `kivy` folder inside the package and running `make force`. This would rebuild for Python 3, assuming you have Cython installed for Python 3 (preferably version 0.21.2, do not use 0.22 as it will not work). I don't have an OSX machine to check this on though, so YMMV.

Best choice is probably to wait, as we should have a 1.9.0 release available soon and that should include a Python 3 package.